# jquery-textcomplete with codemirror.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror

I try to setup **jquery-textcomplete** with **codemirror.net** library with no success.

The codemirror working and the textcomplete not working without errors.

If i disable the codemirror the textcomplete working.

*textcomplete {https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete}
codemirror {http://codemirror.net/}*

---

**Here i my Code**

```
<textarea id="code" name="code" ></textarea>

script

var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
    lineNumbers: true
});

/*
$('.CodeMirror').textcomplete not working
editor.textcomplete not working
*/

$('#code').textcomplete([{
    words: ['apple', 'google', 'facebook', 'github'],
    match: /\b(\w{2,})$/,
    search: function (term, callback) {
        callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
            return word.indexOf(term) === 0 ? word : null;
        }));
    },
    index: 1,
    replace: function (word) {
        return word + ' ';
    }
}]);

/script
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: Any error on console?

Answer (score 1):

You should read the [CodeMirror manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) prior to attempting implementation of  CodeMirror features. That would help you understand the flow better.

The problem with your code is that CodeMirror hides the textarea given to the instance and introduces other elements to show the code in the editor. So, referencing to `$("#code")` wouldn't work. Instead you should use CodeMirror's existing [AutoComplete](http://codemirror.net/demo/complete.html) feature.